# Why Laravel controller store() inserts null values into DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to insert data into a table MySQL database through the controller store function, but it always inserts null values. I don't know where the problem is.

**Model**

```php
class Office extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('office_name_local', 'office_english_name');
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'office_name_local' => 'required', 'office__name_english' => 'required'
    ]);

    $office = Office::create($validatedData);

    return redirect('/createOffice')->with('success', 'Office is successfully saved');
}
```

**Blade**

```php
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2"
      action="{{route('OfficeController.store')}}">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="office_name_local"> local name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="office_name_local" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="office_name_english"> English name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="office_name_english" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('add') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My route

```
Route::get('createOffice','OfficeController@create')->name('createOffice'); 
Route::post('createOffice','OfficeController@store')->name('OfficeController.store');
```

Comment: can you `dd($office)` right after the create and post it?

Comment: I didn't get anything

Comment: Meaning it dumped a null value? Office object with null attributes? The string 'nothing'?

Comment: where exactly I sholud put  dd($office); because no any change in the form after putting it  after $office = Office::create($request->all());!

Comment: after the `$offic =...` is correct, the form itself shouldn't change but you should see the dump after submitting the form, it should just stop right there and dump the $office variable out.

Comment: I wonder how you are passing through the validation, the field names you are passing and validating are different

Comment: show office table

Comment: `dd($request)` your request before you use validation and also add `{{@csrf}}` in your form and check what data you are getting in your request.

Answer (score 0):

//Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 if ($request->method() == 'POST') {
      $rules = array(
      'office_name_local' => 'required',
      'office__name_english' => 'required'
      );
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if (!$validator->fails()) {
$officeObj = new Office();
    $officeId = $officeObj->create($request);

    return redirect('/createOffice')->with('success', 'Office is successfully saved');
}
}
```

//model

```
function create($request) {
$this->office_name_local = $request->office_name_local;
$this->office__name_english = $request->office__name_english;
$this->save();
 return $this->id;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change routes?

Comment: use this simple post route     Route::post('createOffice', 'OfficeController@store');

Comment: why you are using get method

Comment: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Comment: I using post method strange

Comment: yes.use only post method. get method used for getting data but you want save form data so use post only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196121/discussion-between-php-geek-and-phpfan).